# How to change text opacity in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

How can I change the opacity when the cursor is over the text?

Like in those pictures:

[image: opacity 100%]

[image: opacity 30%]

I'm using TextMeshPro

Comment: If you use buttons, you can change the buttons tint when it's being hovered over.

Answer (score 2):

By using face color's alpha property

```
                                //   R    G   B   A
textmeshPro.faceColor = new Color32(255, 128, 0, 255);
```